# Adding checkbox to select records in a view

Tags: views

I have a list of students and I have added a custom handler to add checkboxes against each student to mark as present. When I use filter, I loose the state of checkbox and I have to use filters because I have many students in the list and are on many pages. Same happen when I move to the next page. How can I retain the state of checked text boxes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a task for [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), this module provides a new view style with checkboxes for a wide array of actions you can perform on the row returned. This also comes with javascript which will allow you to remember selections between paginated pages etc which should also help with your issue.